# CRC: false positive under some circumstances

Tags: networking, computer-science, crc, error-detection

Consider two computers `A` and `B`. `A` has uses `G` and `B` uses `G'` where `G' != G` and of *different* degrees. Computer `A` wants to send a data `D` and it uses CRC for that cause.

The claim says that there couldn't be a scenario where `A` sends a CRC-message corresponding to data `D` and computer `B` will accept it as a valid message. Why is that?

We know that computer `A` sends `D*2^r XOR R` (`r` is the degree of `G`) and computer `B` divides by `G'`. So in other words, why can't `G'`, accidentally, divide `D*2^r XOR R`?

Obviously it has something to do with the fact that `deg(G) != deg(G')` but I didn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright I'll try there. Thanks

Comment: (Apparently I need to wait 40 minutes)